# ECG for fluorescent lamp and grounding

Tags: emc, fluorescent-lamp

I have three [OSRAM Quicktronic DIM T8](https://www.osram.com/ecat/QUICKTRONIC%20DIM%20T8-ECG%20for%20FL%20and%20CFL,%20dimmable%20110%20V-ECG%20for%20fluorescent%20and%20compact%20fluorescent%20lamps-Electronic%20Control%20Gears%20for%20Lamps-Digital%20Systems/com/en/GPS01_1089238/PP_EUROPE_Europe_eCat/) 1x 18W in the same room. One is near the wall outlet, the other two are each about 10 m away. Each one is very close to the respective T8 tube.

While the first one has been grounded, given the proximity of the earth wire in the wall, now I have to connect the other two. I already have several metres of 2 wire electrical cable and maybe I could use that one, instead of buying some additional cable. Besides not having to buy more cables, the 2 wire is also quite more flexible and easy to route.

The ECG devices will be also used in dimmed mode and I plan to locate, just next to the ECG itself in a plastic enclosure, an Arduino or equivalent to add WiFi remote control to the 1-10V dimming.

What are the potential issues resulting from the lack of grounding?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [linked datasheet](https://dammedia.osram.info/media/resource/hires/osram-dam-398967/3323088/493509_Technical%20application%20guide%20QUICKTRONIC%20Intelligent%20DALI%20DIM%20(GB).pdf) says on page 8 "In short: Interference free dimming is not possible without protective earth."

Answer (score 0):

Unless you know how to balance stray noise in STP cable DALI signals with CLC Pi filters tuned to shunt the boost frequency while raising impedance, your Dali signals will be swamped by CM RF noise and/or line noise .

But you won’t be able to pass EMI requirements without a PE or else a great deal of electromagnetic shielding design work like that done in Laptops.

The I in EMI is a bidirectional issue.!!!.

Comment: The question was about the 1-10V version, not the DALI one, but your points stand.